# meteor account-ui logout loading but not callback called

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

`Meteor.logout()` using `account-ui` (or event calling from console

`Meteor.logout(function(err){
   console.log(err);
}`

does not call the callback in both of cases

I tried calling it from event, server side and client side with the same result. still loading and does nothing.

If I create a route just for logout purpose like follows

```
FlowRouter.route('/sign-out', {
  name: 'signOut',
  action() {
    if(Meteor.userId()){
        Meteor.logout((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            FlowRouter.go('/');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

does not logout, but if I refresh the page, the logout takes effect.

That's my list of packages

```
meteor-base@1.0.4  
mobile-experience@1.0.4
mongo@1.1.17 
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4
reactive-var@1.0.11
tracker 

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4
standard-minifier-js@2.0.0
es5-shim@4.6.15
ecmascript@0.7.3
shell-server@0.2.3

jquery
mizzao:jquery-ui

kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
dburles:collection-helpers
aldeed:collection2
raix:handlebar-helpers
fastclick#@1.0.13
spiderable
stolinski:stylus-multi

kadira:dochead

accounts-ui#@1.1.9
accounts-password#@1.3.6

zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks

meteortoys:allthings

check

tap:i18n

email

momentjs:moment

ejson

dburles:google-maps
lukemadera:autoform-googleplace
comerc:bs-typeahead
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:delete-button
comerc:autoform-typeahead
gildaspk:autoform-materialize

udondan:googlefonts 
planettraining:material-design-icons-font
materialize:materialize #http://materializecss.com
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
fortawesome:fontawesome
dapearce:material-icons

yogiben:autoform-file
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:s3
cfs:graphicsmagick
```

It's strange, but that's the way it is in my case. How to solve `Meteor.logout()` to work?

[image: logout loading]

## TEST 1

```
"click .logout" (event){
        console.log("logout1");
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("logout2");
        Meteor.logout();
        console.log("logout3");
        FlowRouter.go('/');
        console.log("logout4");
    }
```

[image: edit try 1]

## TEST 2

```
   Template.Guest_header.onRendered(function(){
    var instance = this;
    console.log("start1 "+Meteor.userId());
    instance.autorun(function(){
        console.log("start2 "+Meteor.userId());
        instance.subscribe("me");
        console.log("start3 "+Meteor.userId());
        instance.$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        console.log("start4 "+Meteor.userId());

    });
});
```

[image: logout]

and after clicking on the `button` having class `.sign-out`

```
 "click .logout" (event){
        console.log("logout1 "+Meteor.userId());
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("logout2 "+Meteor.userId());
        Meteor.logout();
        console.log("logout3 "+Meteor.userId());
        FlowRouter.go('/');
        console.log("logout4 "+Meteor.userId());
    }
```

[image: start]

Comment: ```Accounts-ui``` alone will not do the job. I believe accounts-ui should have one of the accounts handling package such as: ```accounts-password, accounts-facebook, accounts-github, accounts-google, accounts-twitter, or accounts-weibo```. Which one of these are you using?

Comment: accounts-password

Comment: Aside from flow router handling the logout, have you tried to logout based on a simple event from a button? Eg. ```'click #logoutButton' (event) { event.preventDefault(); Meteor.logout(); FlowRouter.go('/'); }```

Comment: Hmm. Can you also add some log statement on the ```onRendered``` of the homepage? - This way we can also keep track whether the home page is actually being rendered. Also, try checking for```Meteor.userId()``` after you call ```Meteor.logout()```. This would essentially return nothing if logout is success. If both the above cases work as they are expected to work, then maybe we could try removing that loading animation template too see if it's the culprit. Note:- I'm not sure why this is happening, but some basic debugging could help give some clues.

Comment: after logout, the ID is still the same, but inside the meteor, the callback is never called (of course in TEST 2 the callback is omitted).